# Regular expression patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have a string x like this while trying to **scrape** a text on website and encounter this problem:

`x = 'P. 4. (5.2x4) abc 5.2x4 aoohrwow'`

I want to create a regex pattern that can take out the `5.2x4`
Due to user's ways is not in the same pattern when they type dimensions, i've had this pattern which can cover almost every circumstances (string y, z ,v for examples) but the x string above.

`y = 'abc 5.2 x 4 nsdf'`

`z = 'abc (5.2)3x 4ohsdf'`

`v = 'abc 5.2(4.) x4. qoqwh'`

With my pattern, what i got from x string is `4.(5.2x4)` but I need `5.2x4` part.

My pattern so far:

```
p = r'[(]?(\s)?(\d+)?(\.)?(\d+)?(\s)?[)]?(\s)?[(]?(\s)?\d+(\.)?(\d+)?(\s)?[)]?' \
    r'(\s)?x(\s)?' \
    r'[(]?(\s)?(\d+)?(\.)?(\d+)?(\s)?[)]?(\s)?[(]?(\s)?\d+(\.)?(\d+)?(\s)?[)]?'
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you for your time.

**Edit**
In general, what I need to extract from a string will have pattern like this:

`(1.2)(3.4)x(5.6)`

Strings I **scrape** from website can miss some part of this.
In the `x` string above, my code miscount `4.` in `P. 4.` as one of the dimension part but in fact, it is not.

Can I search a pattern in the string from end to start? If so, I can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Since your examples vary so much from one to the other, and I'm assuming you want exactly `5.2x4` from each one, I'll give you a snippet of code that does work for the examples that work, and let me know if there are some that fail this:

```py
import re


examples = ["P. 4. (5.2x4) abc 5.2x4 aoohrwow",
"abc 5.2 x 4 nsdf", "abc (5.2)3x 4ohsdf",
"abc 5.2(4.) x4. qoqwh"]

for x in examples:
    stripped = x.replace(' ', '')
    matches = list(map(lambda match: ''.join(match), re.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+)[^x]*?(x\d+)", stripped)))
    
    print(matches)

"""
output:
['5.2x4', '5.2x4']
['5.2x4']
['5.2x4']
['5.2x4']
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might say not clear enough, I editted in the post.